# Do I use a nested list for the following problem statement - but how?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

what data structure should I use to solve the following problem? A list - but how?

A meal delivery service has 3 types of meals at different price points and 3 customers. Currently there is a list for deliveries ordered with each index representing a customer (so Customer 1 ordered 2 meals). How would i calculate the total earnings for the types of meals that each customer ordered?

```
meal_types = [happy meal, kids meal, lunch combo]
deliveries_ordered = [[2,1,3],[3,1,2],[1,1,3]]
meal_price = [1.99, 2.99, 3.99]
```

Comment: How would you iterate through items in a list? Also you are missing the portion about how each meals prices are calculated. It does seem a bit like a homework question.

Comment: can you please tell us what types of meals every customer has ordered? And what is the price of every type of meal?

Comment: Updated question - does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're wanting?:

```
meal_types = ['happy meal', 'kids meal', 'lunch combo']
deliveries_ordered = [[2,1,3],[3,1,2],[1,1,3]]
meal_price = [1.99, 2.99, 3.99]
"""
To grab the inner item in a list, we use deliveries_ordered[0][0] which
returns to 2.
deliveries_ordered = [[[0][0],[0][1],[0][2]],[[1][0],[1][1],[1][2]],[[2][0],[2][1],[2][2]]]
"""

for i in range(len(deliveries_ordered)):
    for j in range(len(deliveries_ordered[i])): # Returns len >> Number of Items in the list.
        x = meal_price[i] * deliveries_ordered[i][j]    # Meal price * Number of orders of meal types.
        print("Customer {} ordered {} {}(s). Price: {}".format(j+1,deliveries_ordered[i][j], meal_types[i], x))
```

Output:

```
Customer 1 ordered 2 happy meal(s). Price: 3.98
Customer 2 ordered 1 happy meal(s). Price: 1.99
Customer 3 ordered 3 happy meal(s). Price: 5.97
Customer 1 ordered 3 kids meal(s). Price: 8.97
Customer 2 ordered 1 kids meal(s). Price: 2.99
Customer 3 ordered 2 kids meal(s). Price: 5.98
Customer 1 ordered 1 lunch combo(s). Price: 3.99
Customer 2 ordered 1 lunch combo(s). Price: 3.99
Customer 3 ordered 3 lunch combo(s). Price: 11.97
```

Comment: Whoa!! i think this is the answer i am looking for! Now, can you explain the nested loop part:
what is deliveries_ordered [i][j]?

Comment: "i" takes the first inner list of the main list. "j" takes the inner list of "i". For example: [[0,1,2],[2,3,1]]. If we do [0][2], It first looks for that inner list first, then grabs the number in that inner list. In this case, it returns 2. Avoid coping this code if it's a school assignment.